# How to set up a Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient PostAsync with basic authorization++

Tags: httpclient, uwp

How to set up a Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient PostAsync with basic authorization and mediatype in addition to key/value pairs in Json?

I cannot find any good documentation or examples on how to do this.

These official sites offer very little documentation on how to solve this:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.web.http.httpclient.aspx

Help appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an solution that worked for me:

```
        Dictionary<string, string> pairs = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        pairs.Add("client_id", Constants.CLIENT_ID);
        pairs.Add("grant_type", "authorization_code");
        pairs.Add("code", code);
        var formContent = new HttpFormUrlEncodedContent(pairs);

        var base64Creds = Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(string.Format("{0}:{1}", Constants.CLIENT_ID, Constants.CLIENT_SECRET)));

        var httpFilter = new Windows.Web.Http.Filters.HttpBaseProtocolFilter();
        httpFilter.CacheControl.ReadBehavior = Windows.Web.Http.Filters.HttpCacheReadBehavior.MostRecent;
        var client = new HttpClient(httpFilter);

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new HttpCredentialsHeaderValue("Basic", base64Creds);

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(new Uri(Constants.GET_TOKEN_URL), formContent);
        client.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
string jsonContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(YourObject);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", AuthenticationTokenString);    
StringContent theContent = new StringContent(jsonContent, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");   
HttpResponseMessage aResponse = await client.PostAsync(new Uri(UrlValue), theContent);
string responseContent = await aResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
client.Dispose();
```

Edit : The above code is using `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` 
But if you would like to use `Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient` check out [this](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/11/23/demystifying-httpclient-apis-in-the-universal-windows-platform/) link

Comment: Doesn't work: This solution uses the old System.Net.Http and not the new Windows.Web.Http.